# I have a question about navigating to the next page conditionally in initstate

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to implement Auto Login with Shared preferences.

What I want to implement is that as soon as  'LoginPage' starts, it goes to the next page without rendering **LoginPage** according to the Flag value stored in Shared preferences.

However, there is a problem in not becoming Navigate even though implementing these functions and calling them from **initstate**. What is the problem?

```
//Login Page
void autoLogIn() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final String userId = prefs.getString('username');
    print("ddddddddddddddd");
    SocketProvider provider = Provider.of<SocketProvider>(context);

    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100)).then((_) {**//I tried giving Delay but it still didn't work.**
      Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil("/MainPage", (route) => false);
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    loginBloc = BlocProvider.of<LoginBloc>(context);

    if(!kReleaseMode){
      _idController.text = "TESTTEST";
      _passwordController.text = "1234123";
    }

    initBadgeList();
    autoLogIn();**//This is the function in question.**
    super.initState();
    print("1111111111111111");

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should show LoginPage widget if user is already logged in and then navigate to main page.

I suggest you to use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) and show either splash screen or loader while performing `await SharedPreferences.getInstance()`. In this case your App widget should look like this:

```
class App extends MaterialApp {
  App()
      : super(
            title: 'MyApp',
            ...
            home: FutureBuilder(
                future: SharedPreferences.getInstance(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.data != null) {
                    final SharedPreferences prefs = snapshot.data;
                    final userId = prefs.getString('username');
                    ...
                    return userId == null ?? LoginPage() : MainPage();
                  } else {
                    return SplashScreenOrLoader();
                  }
                }));
}
```

But if you still want to show LoginPage first, just replace SplashScreenOrLoader() with LoginPage() in code above.